# Combining results from two separate functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, dotnetnuke

- Utilizing ASP with DotNetNuke to loop through listing of repeating radio buttons.
- Utilizing JQuery
- Currently displaying proper result value for weightCalculations function (ex: 3)
- How do I combine the rbtCalculations results with the weightCalculations results?
- Ex: IF rbtCalculations = Very High AND weightCalculations = High THEN
  $('p.custom' + ID).text("5");

  ```
  <input id="rbt_0" name="rbt" value="Very High" checked="checked" onclick="rbtCalculations(this,6559);" type="radio">
  <input id="rbt_1" name="rbt" value="High" onclick="rbtCalculations(this,6559);" type="radio">

  <input id="stakeholders_rbt_0" name="stakeholders_rbt" value="Very High" onclick="weightCalculations(this,6559);" type="radio">
  <input id="stakeholders_rbt_1" name="stakeholders_rbt" value="High" checked="checked" onclick="weightCalculations(this,6559);" type="radio">
  <input id="stakeholders_rbt_2" name="stakeholders_rbt" value="Low to Moderate" onclick="weightCalculations(this,6559);" type="radio">

  <p class="custom6559">3</p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function weightCalculations(value, ID) {
          if (value.value == "High") {
              $('p.custom' + ID).text("3");
          }
          else {
              $('p.custom' + ID).text("2");
          }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just add a `class` to the radio buttons to identify them and a wrapping element to associate all the parts together:

```
<div class="js-weight-calc-wrap">
    <input type="radio" class="js-rbt" ... />
    <input type="radio" class="js-rbt" ... />

    <input type="radio" class="js-weight" ... />
    <input type="radio" class="js-weight" ... />
    <input type="radio" class="js-weight" ... />

    <p class="js-result custom6559"></p>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.js-rbt, .js-weight').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $wrap = $this.closest('.js-weight-calc-wrap'),
            rbtVal = $wrap.find('.js-rbt:checked').val(),
            weightVal = $wrap.find('.js-weight:checked').val(),
            result = rbtVal === 'VeryHigh' && weightVal === 'High' 
                     ? '5'
                     : rbtVal === 'VeryHigh' && weightVal === 'Low'
                         ? '4'
                         : '0';
        $wrap.find('.js-result').text(result)
    });
});
</script>
```

I'd also probably end up create a jQuery plugin to contain all of that logic, so on your page it'd just be a call like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    $('.js-weight-calc-wrap').weightCalculator({
        rbtSelector: '.js-rbt',
        weightSelector: '.js-weight',
        resultSelector: '.js-result'
    });
});
```

### UPDATE

I'd forgotten before that you need to filter the radio buttons when you select them, so that you get the checked one only (was confusing with a `<select/>` element).  After adding `:select` to the selector, it works as expected.  I cleaned it up a little more, and created a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdukes/KKsB2/).

Comment: Thanks for the update! Quick question, what would I need to edit to have the above code run on page load and on change?

Comment: To have an event handler run on load, in addition to on the event, you can just trigger the event right after your define it.  For example, `$(...).change(function () { ... }).change();`, that it, just call `.change()` after defining the `change` event handler

Answer (score 1):

```
function weightCalculations(value, ID) {
        if (value.value === "High" && $('input[name="rbt"]').val() === "Very High") {
            $('p.custom' + ID).text("5");
        }
        else if(value.value === "High"){
            $('p.custom' + ID).text("3");
        }
        else {
            $('p.custom' + ID).text("2");
        }
}
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the name only if contains "rbt"?
('input[name*="rbt"]').val()

Comment: yea thats it using the star selector